# how to split the table heading in booktabs?

Tags: tables, tabularx, booktabs

how to split the column headings? How do I get newline after some word? When I put `\\`, it changes the alignment badly.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
%\setlength{\tabcolsep}{6.2 pt}
\caption{Case studies}
\centering
 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{3cm}ccccc}
    \toprule
\centering Nature of unreliability &  Sender SST & Receiver SST & Implementation SST & Retransmission Bound & Decidability\\


\midrule

Noisy (Single fixed error message) & DSST & DSST & DSST & Unbounded & Yes\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\label{case-studies}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

This what I got:

I just want to split the column title in two rows. How do I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You need a column type that allows for wrapping of its contents, like `p{<len>}`, `m{<len>}` (from the [`array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array)) or `X` (from [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx)). Regular `c`-, `l`- and `r`-columns do not break their contents naturally. Since you're using `tabularx`, the following might be what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{booktabs,tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
  \centering
  \caption{Case studies}\label{case-studies}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{3cm}*{5}{X}}
    \toprule
    \centering Nature of unreliability &  Sender SST & Receiver SST & Implementation SST & Retransmission Bound & Decidability \\
    \midrule
    Noisy (Single fixed error message) & DSST & DSST & DSST & Unbounded & Yes \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I've used [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) just to set the `tabularx` in better light; the margin of the default `article` wasn't wide enough to showcase the typesetting.